# Java: Changing some Lables pause and Change them back dosn´t work

Tags: java

Today a got a Java Problem....

I build my selfe a little Frame with some Buttons and Labels. When i hit the Button i want to change 3 Lables wait a few Seconds and change them back. I relized it with:

```
lKarte1.setText(test.kartendeck[0].iam()); //lKarte1 is the label and iam() returns a String
lKarte2.setText(test.kartendeck[0].iam());
```

this works so far quite good. a few Moments larer i change some more lables 
    if(halt[0].wertigkeit.getValue() >  halt[1].wertigkeit.getValue() ){lPlayer1.setText("PLayer1 Wins!!!!!");}

once again this works also. So after this lines i want to have a break about 2 secs.

```
try{Thread.sleep(2000);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
```

and after the two seconds it should display the "old" lables back.

```
            lPlayer1.setText("Player1");
        lPlayer2.setText("Player2");
        lKarte1.setText("");
        lKarte2.setText("");
```

Now my Problem. When i do it WITHOUT Thread.sleep everything works fine. 
But when i do it with Thread.sleep() and i am klicking the button nothing is displayed and just 2 seconds where nothing happens. I know or better see at the end of the 2 seconds that the lables blink so he do the changes ,,,, but why not the changes bevor he should go to sleep ?????

Comment: Are you using Swing? If so you have a problem blocking the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and that's why "nothing happens" in these 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code invoked from an ActionListener executes on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Thread.sleep() causes the EDT to sleep, which means the GUI can't repaint itself.

Instead you can use a Swing Timer to schedule the update of the text on your JLabel.

See the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You can read the sections on `Concurrency` and `How to Use Timers` for more information.

Comment: thanks i was trying it with a timer and it worked ^^ ^thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're hosing up the main event thread by sleeping there.  Do the sleep in a background thread, then after it's done sleeping update the label text back in the main event thread with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
```